# Ordering search results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about ordering search results with PHP and MySQL codes. For example, I entered "Peter has a car", and there are two entries introducing "Peter" and "car" separately in my database. Since all the entries are arranged alphabetically, the entry of "car" would be shown before that of "Peter". Would it be possible to rearrange the order of search results by according to that of appearance of keywords in a sentence I search? It means "Peter" comes first, and "car" would be the next. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
ORDER BY INSTR('Peter has a car', col)
```

This way rows containing a `col` value of `Peter` will take precedence over rows containing a `col` value of `car`, since `INSTR` will return a lower number for the former.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df277/3)

Comment: Wow, i was about to post a huge PHP solution ... i feel ashamed ._.

Comment: It works! Thanks for your help, Giorgos Betsos! =]

Comment: Thank you Y U NO WORK also.